# Phonegap enable GPS/Location at app runtime

Tags: cordova, geolocation, navigator

I am using jquery-ui-maps and HTML5 geolocation to show to the user a list of locations and I need to leverage the user's geolocation.

So, here is the use case,

1. User does not have GPS/Location Services enabled.
2. User opens the application and navigates to the view that calls [navigator.geolocation](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.2.0/phonegap_geolocation_geolocation.md.html) to get the user's position
3. The app errors out and notifies the user they must enable GPS/Location Services
4. The user then navigates out of the app and enables GPS
5. When the user comes back to the app and tries to view the map (calling the geolocation again) the app still isn't able to use GPS.

I believe I have narrowed it down to being a Phonegap issue where the GPS permissions are initialized at app load and never reevaluated.

My question is, can GPS be enabled during the runtime of the application or does Phonegap require an app reload to use the GPS?

Comment: I made an answer for you.  if you want code to look at, you have to post some sort of code your self.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Phonegap does support realtime update of your GPS.

Here is a direct link:

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.1.0/cordova_geolocation_geolocation.md.html#geolocation.watchPosition

In general its called "watch position", and you can set the refresh timer yourself.

Regarding enabling the GPS during runtime.

Try just to call `navigator.geolocation.watchPosition()`.

Remember to grant access to geolocation on your config.xml as well, but I guess you know that ;)

I hope it helped.

Comment: I will change around my service class that abstracts out the geolocation calls to use `watchPosition()` and get back to you

Comment: Just a note: you don't need to set a refresh timer for `watchPosition()` - the success function will be called and passed a new position each time the OS receives a position update from the GPS Receiver hardware

Comment: Does `watchPosition()` fire when the GPS is turned on?

Comment: I made a plugin for GPS core (ios 8 / android): https://github.com/vitorventurin/CordovaGPS

Comment: I tried this solution but `watchPosition()` still requires to reload the app in order to detect that GPS was turned on while the app was running.   Also, watchPosition will drain your batery since it will keep running in spite of switching to other routes.

Comment: In my experience, watchPosition did not call the error function when the location was turned off, it just stopped firing events. So I had to call getPosition periodically to catch the moment when the location becomes unavailable (Cordova 7 on Android).

Comment: This answer doesn't solve the question made. It is the answer for "How to continuously track user position with cordova?" and not "How to enable GPS on runtime"

Answer (score 2):

after struggling for a while i found a plugin that was able to help me with the same issue

https://github.com/nishantsharmajecrc/cordova-dialog-gps

```
  function calldialog() {
 document.addEventListener("deviceready",function() {
 cordova.dialogGPS("Your GPS is Disabled, this app needs to be enable to          works.",//message
            "Use GPS, with wifi or 3G.",//description
            function(buttonIndex){//callback
              switch(buttonIndex) {
                case 0: break;//cancel
                case 1: break;//neutro option
                case 2: break;//user go to configuration
              }},
              "Please Turn on GPS",//title
              ["Cancel","Later","Go"]);//buttons
  });
  }
```

Comment: Loos like that plugin only supports Android, and no other platforms.

Comment: this plugin is outdated and was only for android. With cordova 8 file system structure has changed. Don't install it, because you have to remove all plugin stuff manually inside package.json, plugin folder, config.xml and so on.