# How to use hardware intents in cordova

Tags: javascript, cordova, ionic-framework

My app relies on NFC and GPS to be activated.

Now in the case one of those are deactivated, i want to show an intent, to redirect to the corresponding setting.

I want to point right into the setting, which is currently not activated. I don't want the user to leave the app and reopen it again. Like in google maps. If your GPS is not active, it will warn you and point directly into android gps settings menu

In java it works like this:

```
startActivity(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_WIRELESS_SETTINGS));
```

Now i need the same functionality in cordova/phonegap.

Did you discover any plugin for this and how does it work ?

Comment: Did you see this answer (for GPS): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19778828/phonegap-enable-gps-location-at-app-runtime

Comment: there are a few plugins to launch intents, search and try them, and if none of them fits your requeriments, just create it yourself

Comment: Nope, the answer is not helpful. I want to point right into the setting, which is currently not activated. I don't want the user to leave the app and reopen it again. 

Like in google maps. If your GPS is not active, it will warn you and point directly into android gps settings menu

Comment: People voting down without reason ? many thanks

Comment: you can refer to this link for answers [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27441993/redirect-to-location-settings-using-cordova-in-android][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27441993/redirect-to-location-settings-using-cordova-in-android

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe what you're looking for is the [Phonegap Diagnostic plugin](https://github.com/oaugustus/phonegap-diagnostic-plugin). Here's some [information](https://github.com/ObjetDirect/phonegap-plugins-1/tree/master/Android/Diagnostic) on how to add the plugin to your project as well as using the plugin.

To point to a setting using javascript:
`cordova.require('cordova/plugin/diagnostic').switchToLocationSettings();`

There is an `isGPSEnabled` flag that would be useful for determining if GPS is on or off. I'm not sure if there is something similar for NFC. The [Phonegap NFC](https://github.com/chariotsolutions/phonegap-nfc) plugin may be useful to you.

*For reference*: Questions similar to yours can also be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27441993/redirect-to-location-settings-using-cordova-in-android) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13006454/use-phonegap-to-check-if-gps-is-enabled).

Comment: In the end, i will write the intent plugin by myself, since this repo is inactive for 1 year, seems to be not compatible with the current cordova version and the key part nfc is missing. But you gave the nearly perfect hint.

Comment: @KonstantinKrass Sorry I couldn't be of more help! Good luck with writing one yourself :)

Comment: if you are on Ionic, you don't need `.require()` all I did was  `cordova plugin add https://github.com/oaugustus/phonegap-diagnostic-plugin.git` and `ionic prepare`